# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Tags: jquery

this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/dev/test/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/dev/test/script.js"></script>
Please select your child's birth date: <br>
<input type="text" id="datepicker"> <br>
<span id="yearsStart"></span>
```

I have no clue why the hell i keep getting the error?

Big thanks in advance.

I cant answer my own question:

Sorry for the question i overlooked a file, i made a setup file which i though was ok,

```
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='C:/dev/group/jquery.min.js'></" + "script>");
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></" + "script>");
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='C:/dev/group/script_new.js'></" + "script>");
```

So for now i added the ui url.

test.html gets setup.js and that loads the 3 above.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: and ofcourse i changed the test.html because i fd that one up as you can see in the first three lines ;)

Comment: Try loading using a HTTP Server...

Comment: Try to refer the files by relative path

Comment: Why do i need a http server, its javascript?

Comment: When asking for help with code, quote the code in question. You've given an error message being generated by your script code, but not posted the script code generating the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery doesn't provide a date picker. If you want to use one, you have to include a library that provides one. Your HTML just shows you including jQuery itself and what I assume is your code in `script.js`.

One such library is [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) (which is not jQuery, it's built *on top of* jQuery), which provides one with the very name you're getting in your error, suggesting that's the one you're trying to use.

Here's a complete example using jQuery UI: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ciwadeqi/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- The style sheet for jQuery UI -->
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Datepicker Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" class="dp">
  <!-- The script for jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- The script for jQuery UI -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Your script -->
  <script>
    $(".dp").datepicker();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for the question i overlooked i file, i made a setup file witch i though was ok,

    document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='C:/dev/group/jquery.min.js'></" + "script>");
    document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></" + "script>");
    document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='C:/dev/group/script_new.js'></" + "script>");

So for now i added the ui url.

test.html gets setup.js and that loads the 3 above.

Thanks for your help.